# Parsing and using properties defined using PYTHON in .properties file

Tags: python, parsing, properties, config

I have a .properties file which stores some keys and values that I would like to use it from my python file.

My test.properties file is something like that:

```
attribute1=username
attribute2=address
attribute3=class
```

I would like to access these attributes from a python file such that when I do something like:

```
attribute1 = "tom123"
attribute2 = "5 Smith Street"
attribute3 = "402"
```

But right now I am wondering how to import the config.properties file in python and start using the properties defined.
Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your config file in a python dictionary like this:

```
config = {}

with open('config.properties', 'r', ) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()  # removes the newline characters
        parts = line.split("=")  # creates a (key, value) tuple
        key = parts[0]
        value = parts[1]
        config[key] = value

attribute1 = config['attribute1']
attribute2 = config['attribute2']
attribute3 = config['attribute3']
```